# Disposing of Virtual Desktop (C#/WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop, virtual-desktop

I have created a Virtual Desktop Manager for a client that allows him to organize his Desktop a little better by separating business from personal, etc etc.

But, before I send it to him, I need to learn how to Dispose of a desktop that was created by him. For example, if I create a new virtual desktop, then later on when I've finished with the program, I would want all virtual desktops that were created to be Disposed of, obviously...

But, months later, I cannot find this documentation on MSDN anymore. It looks like the layout and info has been moved around.

Can someone please help? Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I use CreateDesktop (found it in MSDN, it's surprisingly alot easier than I thought it would be to create a virtual desktop!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN Window Station and Desktop Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687107%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [CreateDesktop Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682124%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) :

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the newly created desktop. If the specified desktop already exists, the function succeeds and returns a handle to the existing desktop. When you are finished using the handle, call the [CloseDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682024%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function to close it.

Comment: Thanks Heandel, I didn't think it was quite relevent that I tell this, but when I used CloseDesktop, I noticed that even though it has been 'Closed' it still exists somewhere, because I can still reference it, and can still see it on the list of Desktops that *were* created. Which is what led me to believe that CloseDesktop doesn't completely kill a Desktop. Kind of like Closing a Form is different from Disposing a Form

Comment: I have checked that it succeeds, so maybe it's a bug somewhere in my code. But I can't see where, it's a very tiny file and have gone over and over it. I'll keep reading around MSDN, see if I can find something